# Counting paragraphs that dont end in a Period, C Language

Tags: c, file, char

Basically i need to find a way to discover if the paragraph ends or not in a Period (.).

At this moment i can already count the paragraphs that the given text has, but im not coming up with anything to check if it ends or not in a Period.

Any help would help me, thank you

```
char ch;
   FILE *fp;
   int paragraph=0;
   int newLine=0;
   fp = fopen("123.txt","r");

   while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF ){

        if(ch=='\n'){
            newLine++;
            if(newLine==2){
                paragraph++;
                newLine=0;
            }
        }
            else{
                newLine=0;
            }


    }
  printf("%d\n",paragraph);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can store the previous character in the else part. Then check if you had two newlines, if the previous character is a period.

Comment: `char ch;` should be `int ch;`.  You are lucky `char` is signed by default on your system, otherwise the program would never stop.  It is still a bug with signed chars, as it would erroneously stop on `'\377'`

Comment: @Wimmel ur explanation was enough for me to figure it out, thank you for the comment, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(ch=='\n'){
            newLine++;
            if(newLine==2){
                paragraph++;
                newLine=0;
            if(temp!='.'){
                ponto++;
            }
            }
        }
            else{
                newLine=0;
                temp=ch;
                }
    }
```